# Any other provider instead of Oraclize

Tags: solidity, contract-development, oracles, external-api

Are there any other providers for calling external APIs in Solidity other than Oraclize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple that I can think of:

- [Chainlink](https://chain.link/) - A decentralised oracle network. Queries are paid for in LINK tokens.
- [Realitio](https://realit.io/) (which I think is what used to be Reality Keys). I haven't used it, so won't comment on how it works. Documentation is [here](https://realitio.github.io/docs/html/).

Other people may know of other services.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What is the best service of these three in your opinion, regarding costs and speed?